Hazelcast - complete data loss when master node is gracefully shutdown and restarted
Java 17 Hazelcast: 5.2.4
Very simple 2 node solution. Identical configuration. Spring boot applications are deployed to VMs.
Members {size:2, ver:4} [ Member [127.0.0.1]:5902 - 1a6fc0b7-bcb9-4630-9c20-b8aece752b82 this Member [127.0.0.1]:5901 - e700c21f-faa1-42c6-996b-7c951df0e3f5 ]
Caching works. I can see that both nodes have the cached data.
After I gracefully shutdown Master node (1a6fc0b7-bcb9-4630-9c20-b8aece752b82 this), I can see that secondary node Claims the mastership. And everything works as expected. I can still access the cached data.
But once the master rejoins with empty cache maps, all cache is gone, wiped.
Anyone has any ideas?
Configuration:
hazelcast:
  shutdownhook:
    enabled: false
  initial.min.cluster.size: 1
  phone.home.enabled: false
  network:
    port: 5901   
    auto-increment: true
    join:
      multicast-enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        members: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
  map:
    eviction-policy: LRU
    max-size-policy: FREE_HEAP_SIZE

Spring boot hook
@PreDestroy
void preDestroy() {
    log.info("Shutting down instance and hazelcast.");
    hazelcastInstance.getLifecycleService().shutdown();
}

Tried with async backups and backups, nothing, same thing is happening.
